# Product of two string arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array :

```
a1=['a','b','c']
```

and another :

```
a2=['d','e','f']
```

How do I create a DataFrame containing all elements in a2 for each element in a1 in Python?

Expected output:

```
a d
a e
a f
b d
b e
b f
c d
c e
c f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and create the DataFrame from it:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

a1=['a','b','c']
a2=['d','e','f']

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(a1,a2))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  a  d
1  a  e
2  a  f
3  b  d
4  b  e
5  b  f
6  c  d
7  c  e
8  c  f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `product` from `itertools`

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: a1=['a','b','c']

In [3]: a2=['d','e','f']

In [4]: list(product(a1, a2))
Out[4]:
[('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'e'),
 ('a', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e'),
 ('c', 'f')]
```

This output produces an iterable of tuples (I've applied `list` for display purposes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(x,y) for x in a1 for y in a2])
df
   0  1
0  a  d
1  a  e
2  a  f
3  b  d
4  b  e
5  b  f
6  c  d
7  c  e
8  c  f
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure `pandas` solution:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a1,a2])).reset_index())

  level_0 level_1
0       a       d
1       a       e
2       a       f
3       b       d
4       b       e
5       b       f
6       c       d
7       c       e
8       c       f
```